# Error: You must supply a valid API key

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagamento-online

Estou tendo o. seguinte problema em node: *"You must supply a valid API key".*

Estou iniciando a conexão com esse código:

```js
pagarme.client
      .connect({ api_key: "pk_test_*****************" })
      .then((client) => client.transactions.all())
      .then((transactions) => console.log(transactions));
```

porem estou tendo esse erro de retorno:

```
Error: You must supply a valid API key
```

também tentei com:

```js
pagarme.client
      .connect({ User: "sk_**************", Password: "" })
```

Porem o seguinte erro aparece:

```js
Error: You must supply a valid authentication object
    at rejectInvalidAuthObject (/Users/lucascarinhanha/Documents/finbo/back-end/node_modules/pagarme/pagarme.js:1313:26)
```

**Alguém sabe como fazer uma conexão com o pagar.me?**

Answer (score -1):

Depois de meses eu consegui resolver esse problema.

Deve-se utilizar a [documentação do pagar-me](https://docs.pagar.me/reference).

para se criar um cliente é só fazer um post com axios ou fetch na url
https://api.pagar.me/core/v5/customers

```js
axios
  .post(`https://api.pagar.me/core/v5/customers`, request.body, {
    auth: {
      username: "sk_test_*************",
      password: "",
    },
  })
  .then(async (res) => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

todo o gerenciamento deve ser feito assim